# How to do a secure erase on a Macbook Pro?

Tags: mac, ssd, macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Pro with SSD and I would like to completely erase every single bits of data on it. How would I do that? On a PC, I would just run Darik's Boot And Nuke, but can I run it on a Mac too, or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to erase the *boot* disk, you will have to boot from the Mac OS X install CD (one should have come bundled with your Mac) and run the Disk Utility program on it. If you want to erase a hard drive that isn't your boot disk, you can run the Disk Utility program that can be found in Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.

To do a secure erase like you want:

1. Open Disk Utility
2. Choose the hard drive you want to erase from the list

   [image: Choose hard drive]
3. Choose "Erase" from the bar at the top

   [image: Erase]
4. Click "Security Options" and choose which erase method you want to use. Make sure you choose one of the "# pass erase" options to do what you want.

   [image: Pass erase]
5. Click erase, and the disk will be erased after being written over with zeroes.

Comment: You don't _have_ to use the OSX install disk to erase the drive, but it is a nice option.  Also doing the 7 and 35 pass erase on an SSD is probably a bad idea due to the limited write lifespan.

Comment: @envalid: Thanks for the suggestions, edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like normal secure erase procedures are [less effective](http://www.macworld.com/article/158061/2011/02/ssd.html) on SSDs. Try [this procedure](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=841182) after wiping the volume in Disk Utility.